# converting JSON to java object

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson

What java class structure should I prepare to return such a JSON ?

Corrected JSON (above one is not valid) :

```
{
    "transactionComparisonTotals": [
        [
            "CurrentFace",
            {
                "value": "1000000",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            },
            {
                "value": "1000",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            },
            {
                "value": "0",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            }
        ],
        [
            "MarketPrincipal",
            {
                "value": "1000000",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            },
            {
                "value": "1000",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            },
            {
                "value": "0",
                "format": "$000.00 ptr"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

For this I need set of java classes. O

So one thing I can do is to produce JSON like :

```
 {
        "transactionComparisonTotals": [
            {
                "key": "coupon",
                "valueAttributes": [
                    {
                        "value": 4.25,
                        "format": "00.00%",
                        "color": true,
                        "sign": true
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 4.26,
                        "format": "$00.00 %",
                        "color": true,
                        "sign": true
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 0.31,
                        "format": "00.00 bp",
                        "color": true,
                        "sign": true
                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

But what I actually want is to have "Key" and "valueAttributes" in just one array without property (as shown in my original JSON).

Comment: The json is not a valid one.

Comment: @JackSparrow look into GSON library to parse son it is really simple.

Comment: I actually want to return such a response, so for that I do need to establish  java class hierarchy right ?

Comment: Looks like I have edited the question and now "on hold" should be removed .

Answer (score 2):

Considering this json file `transaction.json`: (yours is not valid, so i tried to correct it just to get the idea of serialization and deserilization using gson google API).

```
{
    "transactionComparisonTotals": [
         {
            "name": "CurrentFace",
            "info":
            [
                {
                    "value": "1000000",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1000",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                },
                {
                    "value": "0",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name": "MarketPrincipal",
            "info":
            [
                {
                    "value": "1000000",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                },
                {
                    "value": "1000",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                },
                {
                    "value": "0",
                    "format": "$000.00 ptr"
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Create these classes:

*Data class:*

```
public class Data{
    List<TransactionComparisonTotal> transactionComparisonTotals;

    public List<TransactionComparisonTotal> getTransactionComparisonTotals() {
        return transactionComparisonTotals;
    }

    public void setTransactionComparisonTotals(
            List<TransactionComparisonTotal> transactionComparisonTotals) {
        this.transactionComparisonTotals = transactionComparisonTotals;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return transactionComparisonTotals.toString();
    }

}
```

*TransactionComparisonTotal class:*

```
public class TransactionComparisonTotal{
    String name;
    List<Info> info;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Info> getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
    public void setInfo(List<Info> info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n"+name+","+info.toString()+"\n";
    }

}
```

*Info class:*

```
public class Info{
    String value;
    String format;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }
    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value+","+format;
    }

}
```

*This is a simple example of deserilization using gson google API*

```
public class Transaction {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "transaction.json")), new TypeToken<Data>() {
        }.getType());
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
[
CurrentFace,[1000000,$000.00 ptr, 1000,$000.00 ptr, 0,$000.00 ptr]
, 
MarketPrincipal,[1000000,$000.00 ptr, 1000,$000.00 ptr, 0,$000.00 ptr]
]
```